# Problem with PySpark and Kafka Streaming and PySparkML

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, pickle, sentiment-analysis

i'm using wsl with ubuntu and pyspark 3.4.1, i want to be able to perform sentiment analysis on tweets through pyspark and spark streaming, using a model created through the spark ml library.

The tweets are retrieved by a script based on apache kafka that writes them on a topic called "tweet_retriever".
At this point i read that topic with a consumer based on Spark that also do some sentiment analysis on the tweets and sends them to flask, i try to define a function with the preprocessing and the predict of the model like i wrote below:

```
# Load the Naive Bayes model
model = NaiveBayesModel.load("model")

# Define the function for sentiment prediction
def predict_sentiment1(tweet):
    from pyspark.ml.feature import HashingTF, IDF, Tokenizer
    # Tokenize the tweet
    tokenizer = Tokenizer(inputCol="tweet", outputCol="words")
    wordsData = tokenizer.transform(tweet)

    # Apply TF-IDF
    hashingTF = HashingTF(inputCol="words", outputCol="rawFeatures")
    featurizedData = hashingTF.transform(wordsData)

    idf = IDF(inputCol="rawFeatures", outputCol="features")
    idfModel = idf.fit(featurizedData)
    rescaledData = idfModel.transform(featurizedData)

    # Predict the sentiment
    prediction = model.predict(rescaledData)

    if prediction == 1:
        return "positive"
    else:   
        return "negative"

    return prediction

# Register the UDF
spark.udf.register("predict_sentiment1_udf", predict_sentiment1, StringType())

#---------------------------------------------
# Reduce logging
spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")

#connessione a kafka
df = spark.readStream.format("kafka") \
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS) \
    .option("subscribe", KAFKA_TOPIC) \
    .option("startingOffsets", "earliest") \
    .load()

df = df.withColumn("sentiment", expr("predict_sentiment1_udf(value)"))

df = df.groupBy("key").agg(expr("COLLECT_LIST(value) AS value"), expr("COLLECT_LIST(sentiment) AS sentiment"))


# Seleziono le colonne desiderate come output
df = df.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)", "CAST(sentiment AS STRING)")
df = df.select("key", "value", "sentiment") \


#Scrivo i risultati
query = df.writeStream \
    .outputMode("update") \
    .foreach(SendTweetToFlaskApp) \
    .start()

query.awaitTermination()
```

but everything i have tried results in this error :
`cannot pickle '_thread.lock'`. I understand that the reason of the problem is the model can't be serializzed but i dont know how to do to prevent this problem.

Someone know how to do it or what should i read/search to be able to resolve this? any help is appreciated thanks

I try to do all this with a nltk model and it works perfectly so the problem is with the pyspark model.